# Customize datetpicker MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to customize Mui date picker paper. I've tried to change the color of it by passing `PaperProps` styles to the `DialogProps` as the following code. But it doesn't changing.

```
<DatePicker
    label="From"
    value={fromValue}
    DialogProps={{
    PaperProps:{
    sx: {
     '.MuiDialog-paper': {
       padding: 2,
       color:'#172438'
            },
          },
       }
    }}
  onChange={(newValueFrom) => {
  setfromValue(newValueFrom);
   }}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker
   {...props}
   PopperProps={{
      sx: {
         '.MuiPaper-root': {
            padding: 2,
            backgroundColor:'#172438'
         },
      },
   }}
/>
```

For more: [The Ultimate Material-UI v5 DatePicker and TimePicker Tutorial (Plus Styling!)](https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-ultimate-material-ui-v5-datepicker-and-timepicker-tutorial/)